# Multiple instances of my typescript class seem to be pointing to the same data, how do I remedy this?

Tags: typescript, oop

So I've created a simple class:

```
export class myClass {
  private static _instance: myClass;
  public name: string;
  public metrics: Array<Metric>;
  private constructor() {
    this.set_metrics();
    //...
  }

  public static get Instance() {
    // Do you need arguments? Make it a regular method instead.
    return (this._instance = new this());
  }

  public set_model_name( name: string ) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  private set_metrics() {
    this.metrics = _metrics;
  }
}

let metrics: Array<Metric> = [
  {
    a: "one",
    b: "two",
    c: "three"
  },
  {
    a: "four",
    b: "five",
    c: "six"
  }
]
```

My problem is now, when I do this:

```
instance_1 = myClass.Instance;
instance_2 = myClass.Instance;
instance_1.set_metrics([
  {
    a: "seven",
    b: "eight",
    c: "nine"
  },
  {
    a: "ten",
    b: "eleven",
    c: "twelve"
  }
])
```

I find that both instances' metrics seem to be changing?? Is this because when changing the metrics, I am actually changing the original 'let metrics..' defined where I define the class? How to I instantiate different instances, using the same default data - but allow the data to be changeable independently?

I hope this is making sense, I have deviated the example slightly from the actual code to hopefully make it more easy to see some problem

Comment: First of all, I don't see you using the metrics array. Also, are you saying that after `instance_1.set_metrics([` instance_1 automatically has its metrics set to the same thing?

Comment: I think you can just delete the static keyword to make two different instances.

Comment: Your pattern seems to be very confusing. If you need two separate instances why use a static method? Why not just do something like `instance_1 = new myClass();
instance_2 = new myClass();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your setter

```
  private set_metrics(){
      this.metrics = _metrics;
    }
```

looks like you are not receving any value, but setting statically always _metrics which looks like some sort of global variable

```
private set_metrics(value: type){
      this.metrics = value;
    }
```

and then every class work on it's own this.metrics. Or you are just passing to everything the reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

in the example you aren't using your metrics, variable, but anyway you have multiple solutions, you can:

- this data outside the component
- and do:

  instance_1 = myClass.Instance;
  instance_2 = myClass.Instance;
  instance_1.set_metrics([...metrics])

with this approach you are creating a new array.